# regular expression for numbers input

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that do the following:

1. the input has to be all numbers
2. the length has to be 4-7 digits
3. the starting number must be from 1-9

I tried many formats but with no success, can someone help me please?

Comment: Show us what have you tried

Comment: and examples for input and expected matches.

Comment: I tried to use the following expressions: [1-9]\d{3,6}

Comment: and this also [1-9]\d{3,6}$

Comment: `'/^[1-9]\d\d\d\d?\d?\d?/'` or simply `'/^[1-9]\d{3,6}/'`

Comment: `^[1-9]\d{3,6}$` you need the $, otherwise it will match (sub)strings that have more than the max 7 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is

^[1-9][0-9]{3,6}$

Answer (score -1):

try this this is for minumum 4 length and max 7 if you want more change the last number

```
^[0-9]{4,7}$
```

Comment: Wrong, the starting digit cannot be a 0

Comment: and it's also not checking if the other characters are digits. (see my comment)

Comment: Starting digit is [0-9]

Comment: change the number 0 for 1 that it why are you rank me in minus the regax is 100% helpfull